# How to select a link element in mixed content?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to select an `a` element mixed within other text:

```
 User xyz Successfully created
```

### HTML

```
<span>
  User
  <a class="link" href="/users/zyx">xyz</a>
  Successfully created
</span>
```

### XPath

So far, this is what I have tried:

```
//*[@class='toast-message']//*[contains(text(),'User')]//*[contains(text(),'xyz')]/following-sibling::*[contains(text(), 'Successfully created')]
```

I need to include the remaining `Successfully created` text after the `a` tag.

Comment: you should provide some tries and read some tutorials https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp, because then you will never learn it. For your goal try `"//a[@class='link' and contains(text(), 'Successfully created')]"`

Comment: I updated it with what I got so far @Edwin

Comment: **The downvotes are excessive.**  OP has responded to the objections raised in comments within the first half hour and [deserves an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47870213/290085).  How about some downvote reversals and possibly some upvotes to restore balance here?  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @kjhughes. We can't please everyone. Thank you for your answer! It's a great help! :)

Comment: @MielYan, to avoid downvotes update your ticket with more understandable title and description as for now it seem that only KJHughes can understand the point of issue :)

Comment: MielYan: Per @Andersson's suggestion, I have updated wording and formatting on your question to hopefully make it clearer to future readers.  If I have in any way misrepresented your intent, please feel free to adjust.  Thanks.

Comment: @kjhughes Fair enough, I retracted my downvote because the OP replaced the image of code with the actual text. The question as originally formulated was incomplete but it's better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//span[normalize-space() = 'User xyz Successfully created']/a
```

will select the `a` element whose parent `span`'s space-normalized string value is the targeted text.